# How to remove duplicate WORDS in Notepad++?

Tags: duplicates, notepad++

I have a big text file that looks like:

```
Mitchel-2
Anna-2
Witold-4
Serena-3
Serena-9
Witros-3
```

I need so the first word before "-" never duplicates. Any way to remove all except the first one. So if I have like 3000 lines starting with "Serena" but there's always a different number after "-", is there a way to remove 2999 lines of Serena and leave just the first one?

Also Serena is just an example, I have over 200 other words that duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with notepad++. You could use a regex for every name, but since you have over 200, that would be unpractical.

But you can write a program that do it for you. Basically you go through 2 steps:

1) You search for every unique name and save it on a set (doesn't allow for duplicate entries).
2) For every unique name on the set, you search for the duplicates on the file.

I've wrote a simple c++ program that finds the duplicates on a string variable. You can adapt it to a langue of your preference. I compiled it with *Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015* (it doesn't work in [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh))

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    typedef match_results<const char*> cmatch;
    set<string> names;

    string notepad_text = "Serena-1\nSerena-2\nSerena-3\nSerena-4\nAna-1\nSerena-7\nWilson-1\nAna-2\nJohn-1\nAna-3\nJohn-2\nWilson-2";
    regex regex_find_names("^\\w+"); //double slashes are needed because this is in a string

    // 1) Let's find every name

    //sregex_iterator it_beg(notepad_text.begin(), notepad_text.end(), regex_find_names);
    sregex_iterator find_names_itit(notepad_text.begin(), notepad_text.end(), regex_find_names);
    sregex_iterator it_end; //defaults to the end condition

    while (find_names_itit != it_end) {
        names.insert(find_names_itit->str()); //automatically deletes duplicates
        ++find_names_itit;
    }

    // 2) For demonstration purposes, let's print what we've found

    cout << "---printing the names we've found:\n\n";
    set<string>::const_iterator names_it; // declare an iterator
    names_it = names.begin();             // assign it to the start of the set
    while (names_it != names.end())       // while it hasn't reach the end
    {
        cout << *names_it << " ";
        ++names_it; 
    }

    // 3) Let's find the duplicates

    cout << "\n\n---printing the regex matches:\n";

    string current_name;
    set<string>::const_iterator current_name_it; //this iterates over every name we've found
    current_name_it = names.begin();
    while (current_name_it != names.end())
    {
        // we're building something like "^Serena.*"
        current_name = "^"; 
        current_name += *current_name_it; 
        current_name += ".*"; 
        cout << "\n-Lets find duplicates of: " << *current_name_it << endl;
        ++current_name_it;

        // let's iterate through the matches
        regex regex_obj(current_name); //double slashes are needed because this is in a string
        sregex_iterator it_beg(notepad_text.begin(), notepad_text.end(), regex_obj);
        sregex_iterator it(notepad_text.begin(), notepad_text.end(), regex_obj); //this iterates over the match results
        sregex_iterator it_end;
        //string res = *it;

        while (it != it_end) {
            if (it != it_beg)
            {
                cout << it->str() << endl;
            }
            ++it;

        }

    }


    int i; //depending on the compaling getting this additional char is necessary to see the console window
    cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

Input string is:

```
Serena-1
Serena-2
Serena-3
Serena-4
Ana-1
Serena-5
Wilson-1
Ana-2
John-1
Ana-3
John-2
Wilson-2
```

Here it prints

```
---printing the names we've found:

Ana John Serena Wilson

---printing the regex matches:

-Lets find duplicates of: Ana
Ana-2
Ana-3

-Lets find duplicates of: John
John-2

-Lets find duplicates of: Serena
Serena-2
Serena-3
Serena-4
Serena-5

-Lets find duplicates of: Wilson
Wilson-2
```